# Mac PackageMaker : Do actions only if a file doesn't exist

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

How can I make some conditional actions only if a file **doesn't exist**?

I found the requirement check "If file exists" but not "If file doesn't exist".

Perhaps using an apple script in the pre-install check?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example...

```
set someFile to (path to desktop as text) & "sample.txt"

tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists file someFile) then
        -- do something here
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your script works perfectly in AppleScript Editor, but when I try to include my test in the postInstall action, the installer return an installation error. Shall I return something like "return true" or something like that to specify that my script execution has been successfully done?

Comment: Hello, after few research on the web, the "applescript" files can be called from pre-install and post-install script using the shell command "osascript your_applescript_file.scpt".